# can I change where res.send('success') redirects to?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm making a file upload and it works perfectly fine. But when I upload a file I use `res.send('success')` to send a success message. And this **automatically redirects me to two pages backward**. It is not a problem for me. But I **need to know how this work** and need to know **'can I change where this redirects me to?'**
Here's my code,

```
  router.post('/schemes/edit-data/:fname',fileupload(),function(req,res){
  var sampleFile = req.files.pho;
  var dir='./public/uploads/schemes/'+sampleFile.name;
  schemeData.findOne({fileName:sampleFile.name},function(err,file){
    if(file==null){
      schemeData.update({fileName:req.params.fname},{
        fileName:sampleFile.name,
        year:req.body.year,
        grade:req.body.grade
      },function(err){
        if(err){
          console.log(err);
        }
        var fpath=path.join(__dirname,'../public/uploads/schemes/'+req.params.fname);
        fs.unlink(fpath,function(err){
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }
          sampleFile.mv(dir, function(err) {
            if(err){
              return res.status(500).send(err);
            }else{
              req.flash('success','Scheme Data saved successfully');
              res.send('success');///////////////////////////////////////////////
            }
          });
        });
      });
```

It is a bit hard to see. Sorry for the inconvenience. And thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple use

```
res.redirect('/route')
```

Comment: Also I found an answer.
What success does is, it just sends a success message to front end. It doesn't participate in any redirecting. In the frontend we can use jquery and ajax to redirect anywhere when we receice the success message.